Create a cfg for the language $L = \{w ∈ \{a,b,c\}^* : |w| = 3n_a(w)\}$
All I know about this language is that it is equivalent to the following:
$$L = \{w \in \{a,b,c\}^{∗} : n_b(w) + n_c(w) = 2 * n_a(w)\}$$
but I have absolutely no idea how to create a CFG for it.

Related problems: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125141/pda-for-l-w-n-awn-bw-2n-cw, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125844/what-is-context-free-grammer-of-l-w-n-cw-ne-n-aw-n-bw

For each $a$, you must have either two $b$s or two $c$s, or a pair of $b$ and $c$. Also these $a$, $b$ and $c$ can appear in any order. This should be a sufficient hint to devise a CFG.

 For $n_c(w) =0$ we can write $S \rightarrow SaSbSbS | SbSaSbS | SbSbSaS | \lambda$


So that would make about 48 production rules, right?
12 for permutations of {a, b, b, S},
12 for permutation of {a, c, c, S},
24 for permutation of {a, b, c, S} and 1 for epsilon transition, right?

Please see the updated answer.

i'm having a bit of a trouble understanding the logic behind it, could you explain it pleas?

See if you can prove the following generates all string with equal number of $a$s and $b$s: $S \rightarrow SaSbS | SbSaS | \lambda$
